# How Can I Make My Recent data appear first from database php

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have some data in my database and i displayed them in my browser but the arrangement it had was from the oldest data to the newest eg the one added yesterday shows before the one added today but i want the one i added today into the database to appear before the one yesterday in my site just like stackoverflow questions in the front page.

**Code**

```
    function postTrade($conn) {

    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Copenhagen');

    $postSql = "SELECT * FROM userpost";
    $postR = mysqli_query($conn, $postSql);

    while($postrow = mysqli_fetch_array($postR)) {
        $ptitle = $postrow['postTitle'];
        $pimg = $postrow['postImg'];
        echo '<div class="post">
                          <div class="img">
                                <img src="create/images/'.$pimg.'" alt="Post Image">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="post-info">
                                        <h3 class="post-title">'.$ptitle.'</h3>
                                        <div class="post-flex">
                                            <span class="post-date">'.date("Y-m-d H:i").'</span>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>';
    }
}

postTrade($conn);
```

Please how can i do it.

Comment: Please provide userpost table structure.

Comment: Add on ORDER BY clause to your database query. (These are absolute basics of working with databases, so please go read up on the necessary details yourself using that keyword, if you are not familiar yet.)

Comment: ... assuming there is a `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME` field on the table of course - that's not actually been explicitly stated.

Comment: Status of the question please?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to add `ORDER BY` clause to your SQL query:

```
 $postSql = "SELECT * FROM userpost ORDER BY date_time_field DESC";
```

Look more information on [documentation](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-order-by/)

Answer (score 0):

if you have Date or Created_at or anything have a valid date you can use order by 
else if you havent this column you can sort by id from last

```
   function postTrade($conn) {

    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Copenhagen');

    $postSql = "SELECT * FROM userpost ORDER BY `id` DESC";
    $postR = mysqli_query($conn, $postSql);

    while($postrow = mysqli_fetch_array($postR)) {
        $ptitle = $postrow['postTitle'];
        $pimg = $postrow['postImg'];
        echo '<div class="post">
                          <div class="img">
                                <img src="create/images/'.$pimg.'" alt="Post Image">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="post-info">
                                        <h3 class="post-title">'.$ptitle.'</h3>
                                        <div class="post-flex">
                                            <span class="post-date">'.date("Y-m-d H:i").'</span>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>';
    }
}

postTrade($conn);
```